# Restlet Server cannot be resolved

Tags: rest, restlet

im trying to setup a simple Restlet Server. I've reading the tutorials from the Restlet Website. I have bind the "org.restlet.jar" file to my classpath and try to run this code:

```
 import org.restlet.resource.Get;
import org.restlet.resource.ServerResource;


public class data_server extends ServerResource {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  
        // Create the HTTP server and listen on port 8182  
        new Server(Protocol.HTTP, 8182, data_server.class).start();  
    }  

    @Get  
    public String toString() {  
        return "hello, world";  
    }  

}
```

And then Eclipse show me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Server cannot be resolved to a type
    Server cannot be resolved to a type
    Protocol cannot be resolved to a variable
    Part03 cannot be resolved to a type

    at data_server.main(data_server.java:9)
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: just stumbled across this -for which you have bound to have found the answer by now - but it looks to me like some imports are missing/incorrect.